# Sending Bitcoins from a Mastercoin Address

Tags: omni

Is there any danger in sending any remaining bitcoin funds that are still sitting in a Mastercoin address, i.e. the bitcoin address from which one sent funds to the Exodus address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's completely safe.

To send mastercoins you have to use one of the mastercoin clients - you can't accidentally send mastercoins by working with a Bitcoin wallet.